# D3 Time scales based only on hours and not bound to dates

Tags: d3.js

i'm stuck a really interesting problem,

I'm Creating a line chart Comparing booking & cancellations of multiple flights up to the point of departure. so the X axis have to show a countdown of only hours like 72 - 48 - 24 - 12 - 6 - 0, how can i achieve these kind of scales using d3s available linear scales & time scales. ?

i'm currently using linear scare but its base 10, so wont work like expected

when using time scales its showing dates, but it should not be bound to dates, only have to show 144 hours before flights departure.

Your help will be much appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you aware of time scales in D3? You could probably achieve what you want with ``scale.ticks( d3.time.hour, /* some function */ )``. https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales

Comment: I tried that, but its showing dates, i only want to show hours without bind to dates

Comment: Then how about using a linear scale and something like ``scale.tickFormat( function(d) { /* check for valid hour, else return nothing */})``? That way only valid hours have a visible tick.

Answer (score 0):

I Found a solution

Im not sure if its the right way of doing it but it works for me, basically we have to change the format of the ticks to represent minutes instead of decimal numbers

This is what i did

Created a linear scale to convert decimal to minutes

```
var dectomin = d3.scale.linear().rangeRound([0 , 60]).domain([0,1]);
```

and use tickFormat function to format the tick lables on axis component

```
var chartXAxis  = d3.svg.axis().scale(chartXScale).orient("bottom")
                    .tickFormat(function(n){ 
                        if(n % 1 === 0) {
                            return n;                            
                        } else {
                            var f = Math.floor(n);
                            var d = n - f;
                            return f + ":" + chartXScaleTime(d);
                        }
                    });
```

Thanks [prayerslayer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/490524/prayerslayer) For this idea